# How are shared/placed the int of the ProtoMember/ProtoInclude in ProtoBuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I've several questions on how/where the ID of a `[ProtoContract]` should be declared.

Imagine the following code:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(SomeClassA))]//1) CAN I USE 1 here?
public abstract class RootClass{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int NodeId {get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(SomeClassC)]//2) Should I declare this here or directly on the RootClass?
//3) Can I use the id 100 here?
//4) Can I use the id 1 here? or member + include share the id?
public class SomeClassA : RootClass{

    [ProtoMember(1)]//5) CAN I USE 1 here? Since the parent already use it but it's a different class
    public String Name{get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SomeClassC : SomeClassA {
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Count{get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SomeClassD : SomeClassA {
    [ProtoMember(2)] //6) Can I use 2 here? Since SomeClassC already use it and is a sibling?
    public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

I've put several number with questions:

1. CAN I USE 1 here?
2. Should I declare this here or directly on the RootClass?
3. Can I use the id 100 here?
4. Can I use the id 1 here? or member + include share the id?
5. CAN I USE 1 here? Since the parent already use it but it's a different class
6. Can I use 2 here? Since SomeClassC already use it and is a sibling?

The thing is that we have a huge model with a lot of classes, which all herits from the same object, so I'm trying to figure out to which ID I should take care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version:

- the set of field numbers for a type is the **union** of the numbers defined against **members** (fields and properties), and the numbers defined for **immediate subtypes** (includes)
- the set of field numbers must be unique within **that single type** - it is not required to consider base types or derived types

Longer version:

The reason for this is that subtypes are *essentially* mapped as optional fields:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(SomeClassA))]
public abstract class RootClass{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int NodeId {get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(SomeClassC)]
public class SomeClassA : RootClass{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public String Name{get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SomeClassC : SomeClassA {
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

is, in terms of `proto2` syntax:

```
message RootClass {
    optional int32 NodeId = 1;
    optional SomeClassA _notNamed = 100;
}
message SomeClassA {
    optional string Name = 1;
    optional SomeClassC _notNamed = 200;
}
message SomeClassC {
    optional int32 Count = 2;
}
```

Note that at most 1 sub-type field will be used, so it can be considered `oneof` for the purposes of `.proto`. Any fields relating to the sub-type will be included in `message SomeClassA`, so there is no conflict with `RootClass` and they do not need to be unique. The numbers only need to be unique per `message` in the `.proto` sense.

---

To take the specific questions, then:

1. no, because that would conflict with `NodeId`
2. it should be declared on `SomeClassA`; protobuf-net is only expecting immediate descendants, and it keeps the numbering consistent and conveniently readable, since the field number is only required to not conflict with the members of `SomeClassA`
3. yes you can; there is no conflict
4. no, because that would conflict with `Name`
5. yes you can; there is no conflict
6. yes you can; there is no conflict - although actually protobuf-net won't even think of `SomeClassD` as a sibling *anyway* (it isn't advertised anywhere as an include) - but if there was a `[ProtoInclude(201, typeof(SomeClassD))]` on `SomeClassA`, then it would be fine. This would change our `.proto` to add:

   ```
   optional SomeClassD _alsoNotNamed = 201;
   ```

   to `message SomeClassA`, and add:

   ```
   message SomeClassD {
       optional int32 Count = 2;
   }
   ```

---

Note that protobuf-net doesn't *actually* generate the `.proto` syntax unless you explicitly ask for it (via `GetSchema<T>` etc) - I'm including it purely for illustrative purposes in terms of the underlying protobuf concepts.

Comment: That is a relief, very good surprise! Thank you very much! Very complete answer

Comment: Didi you see my other questioN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143602/how-to-avoid-having-duplicate-objects-in-wcf-over-protobuf It's the last one that keep me going

Comment: @J4N yes, but I haven't had time to look at it yet; partly because of the mention of WCF which makes it non-trivial to test. It is possible that the question doesn't *actually* relate to WCF - but: I just haven't looked at it yet (day job, family duties, etc); I can probably look later

Comment: Sure I understand